# Maximo Favorite Application Portlet

Tags: portlet, maximo, favorite

I had defined Asset Application to show only those assettypes I need for necessary security group. I also had defined new Start center for this group and added Asset application as favorite apps.

When I open favorite application, in left columns is tab "Available queries" and show All records. Can I somehow configure this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 posibilities to do this:

**Option No. 1.**

1. Go to Apllication Designer - Necessary aplication
2. Choose presentation options
3. Insert SQL type Where Clause - what result you want to see (`variable='name'`)
4. Insert Restriction - what results you don't want to see (`not variable='name'`)
5. Go to Application Page
6. Filter results
7. Save results as new query and make it default

**Option No. 2.**

1. Repeat steps 1-5 in option No. 1
2. From Drop down list in toolbars Search field choose Where clause.
3. Insert SQL WHERE statement with restriction you need to see